# How Can I remove these quotes from the Javascript output?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

**I have a collection of data like this -**

```
[
 0: {latitude: "0", longitude: "0", user_country_name: "-", user_country_code: "-", total_visitors: 4}
 1: {latitude: "-33.867851", longitude: "151.207321", user_country_name: "Australia", user_country_code: "AU", total_visitors: 1}
 2: {latitude: "-23.960831", longitude: "-46.333611", user_country_name: "Brazil", user_country_code: "BR", total_visitors: 1}
 3: {latitude: "45.411171", longitude: "-113.468712", user_country_name: "Canada", user_country_code: "CA", total_visitors: 2}
 4: {latitude: "47.366669", longitude: "8.55", user_country_name: "Switzerland", user_country_code: "CH", total_visitors: 1}
]
```

**I get the result by using**

```
var location_data = [];
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data: data, 
    success: function(data)
    {
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(obj)
        obj.forEach(function(item) {

          var data = { latLng: [parseFloat(item.latitude), parseFloat(item.longitude)], name: item.user_country_name }
      
          location_data.push(data);
        })
    } 
  });

  console.log(location_data)
```

**Output :** Something like this

```
[
 0: {latLng:  Array(2), name: "-"}
 1: {latLng:  Array(2), name: "Australia"}
 2: {latLng:  Array(2), name: "Brazil"}
 3: {latLng:  Array(2), name: "Canada"}
 4: {latLng:  Array(2), name: "Switzerland"}
]
```

But I want something like the following, I mean  display the item of the object like **[-33.867851, 151.207321]** not as array(2);

**Expected Output:**

```
[
     0: {latLng: [0,0], name: "-"}
     1: {latLng: [-33.867851, 151.207321], name: "Australia"}
     2: {latLng: [-23.960831, -46.333611], name: "Brazil"}
     3: {latLng: [45.411171, -113.468712], name: "Canada"}
     4: {latLng: [47.366669, 8.55], name: "Switzerland"}
]
```

Comment: If you want text, why are you setting it to an Object to innerHTML? You can use JSON.stringify() but it will add more quotes than you probably want....

Comment: sorry that was my mistake. I have updated the question. thanks.

Comment: You are printing that result in console ? see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/423w0frg/1/)

Answer (score 1):

The input data itself has the latitudes/longitudes as string, not number. Strings are any kind of text, wrapped around "" quotes, as in your input data. You need to convert it to a number. For us humans, "-33.867851" and -33.867851 are the same intuitively. But for computers they are completely different things: one is text and one is number, regardless of there is a number as the text (it could be anything).

You can either:

- Send the latitudes/longitudes as number directly (-33.867851 instead of "-33.867851")
- Or if you can't control the input data, use `parseFloat` in your foreach where you set data, e.g. `latLng: [parseFloat(item.latitude), parseFloat(item.longitude)]` to convert string representation of the number into an actual number.

Comment: thankyou. but how can I remove this array 2 from the text? is there any way?

Comment: i don't get what you mean by array 2?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that in the line where you set the data.

```
var data = { latLng: [parseFloat(item.latitude), parseFloat(item.longitude)], name: item.user_country_name }
```

You are creating an array which results in the printout being `array(2)` The solution is to add single or double quoutes to that line. there is also no need to parse the data since it is already a string.

```
var data = { latLng: "["+item.latitude+", "+item.longitude+"]", name: item.user_country_name }
```

Comment: It shows `{latLng: "[37.56826, 126.977829]", name: "Korea (Republic of)"}`

But I need **" " this quotes** to be removed in latLng items. I mean -

    {latLng: [37.56826, 126.977829], name: "Korea (Republic of)"}